# PrestoDB: insert fails with null error message

Tags: hive, presto

I'm trying to insert data into a table using Presto.

I'm doing a simple insert on a table that I created in hive, which is as simple as possible (stored as text):

```
CREATE  TABLE `stam`(
  `name` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

When I try to insert using either of the queries below:

```
insert into stam values('test');

insert into stam select 'test' from another_table;
```

Both fail - I get the following error:

> Query 20141128_150952_00004_vaf59 failed: null

I see nothing in the logs, and I have no idea how can I debug these.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

well, I've found the answer in the code:
`// Hive connector currently does not support insert`